# visualise Orientation map with opencv or matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, orientation, visualization

I'm programming a fingerprint recognition system ..and I get the orientation field map but i want to visualise the result befor continuing the rest of the program.

Is there any source code with openCv to do this faster or should I write the code my self

what about Matlab can it visualise an orientation matrix

the result I want is to visualise the b image ( I have already calculate it)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XOdv.jpg

Comment: What have you done thus far? We could help if we know how we could help.

Comment: what kind of values are in the orientation map? Floating point between 0 and 2*pi or two elemented (normalized) vectors? One orientation for each pixel or for each (unsorted) line segment?!? You said you calculated the orientation information already, how is the data formatted? Can you provide and explain some sample data? I don't think openCV or matlab have a `visualizeMyCalculatedFingerprintOrientation` method ;)

Comment: Yep I have a matrix of angles between (0- 2*pi) some kind of   theta= atan (y/x) .. one orientation for each block of [16*16] pixels
I though there is a simple way to do it because there is always a representif image in the articles talking about fingerprint recognition this had let me think about a ready code to do the things faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Matlab: Have a look at the Quiver plot: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html

For OpenCV: I don´t think there is a function you could use.
You would have to write it yourself.